# Web API - Model binding error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Say I have this model:

```
public class MyFormModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Date From is required")]
    public DateTime? DateFrom{ get; set; }    
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public WebResponse MyMethod([FromBody] MyFormModel form)
{
    //blah blah
}
```

Body of post:

```
{
    "DateFrom": "aaa"
}
```

And when posting to the WebAPI, I set the `DateFrom` value as `"aaa"`. The default binding is returning the following error message (in ModelState):

> The value 'undefined-undefined-undefined' is not valid for DateFrom.

How do I customise the error message if the binding fails. Eg. I want an error message like: `"DateFrom is invalid"` if the binding fails.

Comment: Why is the property a `DateTime?` instead of a `DateTime` if it's required?

Comment: And please show how/what you are posting to the API.

Comment: @DavidG updated post with more info

Comment: Well for a start, that's not valid JSON, the property name needs to be surrounded with quotes too e.g. `{ "DateFrom": "aaa" }`

Comment: @DavidG Fixed. It was just a sample, but you get the point

Comment: Well unfortunately we need exact code or it's impossible to help diagnose. As it stands, I can't see how you would get the error you claim.

Comment: @DavidG I'm guessing the message is coming from the default .net model binder. I want to be able to change this default message

Comment: @DavidG Also that error was in ModelState

Comment: Well you could make the property a `string` and check manually in the action.

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom model binding for DateTime type?  You're wanting to override a default behavior and the only way I can see to do it in this case is with a custom binding.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.0